# A nice conjecture about convexity

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, convex-analysis

Let $L : C([0,1]) \rightarrow \mathbb R$ linear continuous, with $L(id)=0$, $L(1)=0$ and $L(c)>0$

($c:x \rightarrow x^2$)

Is it true that $\forall f\in C([0,1])$ convex, $L(f) \geq 0$ ?

$C([0,1])$ with the uniform norm.

Comment: Just to be sure: $L(\mathrm{Id})$ and $L(1)$ should be the zero-functions? And the image of the function $c$ should be a function that is non-negative and non-zero, or should it be nowhere zero?

Comment: Excuse me, it's a typo

Comment: Can you tell us what makes this conjecture seem "nice" to you?

Comment: If it's true, it's an intersting general result

Comment: OK, suppose it *is* true; can you say why it's "interesting"? And please, please, don't just say "because it's fascinating" or some other adjective. Explain to me (a person without much experience in analysis) why such a result would intrigue analysts.

Comment: I currently try to build a counterexample. The point which I find strange (or 'interesting') is, that the condition is only a condition on a finite dimensional subspace $U := \mathrm{span}\{ \mathrm{Id}, 1, c \} \subseteq C( [0,1] $.
But the subspace of convex functions is larger, i.e. how could a condition on $U$ imply a condition for all convex functions...

Comment: There exists a theorem which only the conditions one some functions (square, identity and constant) give a general consequence, like here, but I don't remember the name of this result.

Comment: @SteffenPlunder: you've essentially done it - any linear functional can be extended from a finitely-dimensional subspace of $C([0,1])$ to a continuous linear functional on the whole $C([0,1])$. Thus there is certainly an $L$ such that $L(x\mapsto x^3)=-1$, say.

Comment: @Dattier: Do you mean the Korovkin theorems?

Comment: @metamorphy: Yes, that sound good. But I still struggle to find a concrete counterexample :D

Comment: @SteffenPlunder : yes, Korovkin result's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $L(f)=27f(0)-72f(1/3)+63f(2/3)-18f(1)$. You get
$$L(1) = L(\mathrm{Id}) = 0, \quad L(x\mapsto x^2) = 2, \quad L(x\mapsto x^3) = -2.$$

Comment: What about the case $L(x\rightarrow 1)=L(x\rightarrow x)=0$ and $\forall n \in \mathbb N_{\geq 2} L(x\rightarrow x^n) \geq 0$ ?

Comment: (I've removed my prior comments due to incorrect reasoning which caused a lengthy discussion. Here is the same counterexample with the reasoning fixed.) Take $L(f)=f(1)-3f(2/3)+3f(1/3)-f(0)$ (third-order finite difference). It is easy to check that $L(x\mapsto x^n)\geqslant 0$, with equality for $n<3$. Now $f(x)=3x^2-x^3$ is convex on $[0,1]$, but $L(f)=-2/9$.

Answer (score 1):

By defining $L(1)=0$, $L(x)=0$, $L(x^2)=1$, and $L(x^3)=-1$; this gives a linear functional $L$ on the span of $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$ that is continuous on the span. The Hahn-Banach theorem provides a continuous extension. The function $x\mapsto x^3$ is convex, but its image is negative.